# Subgroup of direct product of Q

Tags: group-theory

I know the classification of subgroup of $ \mathbb{Q}$  exist. Is there a method to classify all subgroups of $ \prod\limits_{i=1}^n  \mathbb{Q} $  ?

Comment: Classification up to equality, or up to isomorphism? It's different (both in $\mathbf{Q}$ and in $\mathbf{Q}^n$).

Comment: @YCor I mean up to isomorphism. Actually i only know up to isomorphism in $ \mathbb{Q} $. What is the difference ?

Comment: In $\mathbf{Q}$ the subgroups $\mathbf{Z}$ and $(1/2)\mathbf{Z}$ are distinct but isomorphic. In a finitely generated (nonabelian) free group, the classification of subgroups up to isomorphism is quite trivial, but the "classification" of subgroups (up to equality) is very rich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no satisfactory classification even for $n=2$. Here’s a survey by Simon Thomas on work giving precise results about the set-theoretic complexity of the problem (which I don’t pretend to understand):

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2687752

Comment: I assume you interpret the question as "classification up to isomorphism".

Comment: Then it somewhat depends on what you call "satisfactory", but indeed it's strictly more complicated for $n=2$ than for $n=1$. Even the classification of subgroups of $\mathbf{Z}[1/p]^2$ up to isomorphism is quite interesting; it's closely related to classifying orbit of $\mathbf{P}^1(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ modulo the action of $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[1/p])$.

Comment: @YCor Yes, “up to isomorphism” is what I assumed the OP meant. But you’re right, they might well have meant “up to equality”.